# The telethon sync version works, but why doesn't the Telethon async iterator work?

Tags: python, asynchronous, telethon

I wrote a synchronized message text downloader using telethon on python 3.9, but when I converted it to async nothing printed.

I found that by making the code simpler and simpler, the code stops at the for .. in client.iter_messages.

```
sourcec=PeerChannel(channel_id=cid)
def main():         
    for message in client.iter_messages(sourcec, 5):
    print(message.text)
main()
```

worked as expected.

```
sourcec=PeerChannel(channel_id=cid)
async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(sourcec, 5):
        print(message.sender.username)
asyncio.run(main())
```

nothing printed

Rebooting the machine after reinstalling Telethon doesn't even work the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/asyncio.html?highlight=coroutine#what-are-async-await-and-coroutines)

I expected that code print messages like sync version, but nothing printed

Comment: You're printing two different things in the two cases. don't forget the username can be unavailable in case of private chats. and how can you prove cid is equal in both cases too. if you can clear up the following and test it further and it still shows issues, edit your question with extra clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

`asyncio.run` creates a new event loop. If you connected the client in a different event loop, it won't work (`asyncio` will be running a loop different to the loop being used by the client).

You should either connect the client inside the `async def` as well or use `client.loop.run_until_complete()` instead. `telethon.sync` is a hack which wraps every client method in the latter for you.